# My own concatenate function doesn't change destination string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've tried debugging this code but even as I cycle through the string in the while loop, it doesn't look like I'm cycling anything. The destination array is unchanged after the function is called.

```
void stringConcatenate(char * destination, char * source)
{
int index1 = 0; //for cycling subscripts
int index2 = 0;

while (destination[index1] != '\0') //cycle to end of first string
{
    index1++;
}
index1++;   //to get to null character
while (source[index2] != '\0')  //cycle through second string appending along the way
{
    destination[index1] = source[index2];
    index1++;
    index2++;
}
destination[index1] = '\0'; //append null point
```

}

Comment: `"The destination array is unchanged"` You *think*. As Captain Obvlious pointed out, you've just left the NUL terminator in place. Also, are you checking to ensure that the `destination` buffer is large enough to hold the `source` data, too? See for example `strncat`, as opposed to `strcat`.

Comment: Also, you indicate that you're running VS 2010 - This means you have a built-in debugger *right in front of you*. **Learn to use it!** Effective debugging skills are orders of magnitude faster than posting to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The line incrementing `index1` after the first `while` statement should not be there.

```
index1++; //to get to null character <-- incorrect.
```

`index` already points to the terminator. By incrementing it there you end up appending the string one character *after* the terminator.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way to Concatenate two strings using pointer,you should try this also.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void concat(char* ,char* );
    void main(void)
      {       
          char str1[25],str2[25];
           printf("\nEnter First String:");
          gets(str1);
           printf("\nEnter Second String:");
           gets(str2);
          concat(str1,str2);                                //1
         printf("\nConcatenated String is %s",str1);
    }
      void concat(char *s1,char *s2)
      {
         while(*s1!='\0')                                //2
         s1++
       while(*s2!='\0')                                //3
          {
          *s1=*s2;                                 //4
          s1++;                                         
          s2++;                                         
        }
       *s1='\0';                                      //5
}
```